# Do these "exponentially convex" functions have a standard name?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request, convex-analysis, terminology

Do functions $f:(0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ which satisfy the property that $x \to f(e^x)$ is convex have a standard name in the mathematical literature?

Equivalently, define $g:\mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$ by setting $f(x)=g(\log x)$. So, our property is the convexity of $g$.

Here we precompose with $\log x$; this is not to be confused with the notion of a ["Logarithmically convex function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function#:%7E:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,and%200%20%3C%20%CE%B8%20%3C%201.), where we first apply $f$, then take the logarithm.

I wonder whether there is a standard name for such functions $f$.

*Comment:*

This property does not imply the convexity of $f$, or vice versa:

Indeed, consider $f(x)=
(\log x)^2$, and $f(x)=(x-1)^2$.

Comment: Interesting notion; I have not seen it named in any of the literature I've read.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a standard name, but you may perhaps try *convex up to an exponential*, if it makes sense in English (I am not an English native speaker...).
You should of course precisely define this notion before using it.